# Python Generator Memory Usage

Tags: python

I recently came across this great stackoverflow post explaining the concept of yield [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python).

As such I did some exploring myself and found that the size of a generator, although substantially smaller than that of an iterable (list in this case) that the generator still holds a very small chunk of memory.

Whats more interesting to me is if i increase the range(100) -> range(10000), and add in intermediate variables e.g. `test = i * 100 + 2 ... yield test`, that the memory usage of `b` remains a constant 112 bytes, while that of `a` increases as I would expect. Is this memory independent of the size of the function referenced for delayed execution in the generator?

```
from sys import getsizeof

a = [i for i in range(100)]

def b(): 
    for i in range(100):
        yield i
        
b = b()

getsizeof(a) # 920
getsizeof(b) # 112
```

So the question is - what does `b`'s memory actually hold?

Comment: `b` is just an interrupted function.  When you do the `yield`, the "stack frame" for the function is essentially frozen, and the function returns.  When the caller does something that triggers a `next`, the function is unfrozen and continues to execute as if it has never stopped.  There's no extra memory.  Your variable `b` does not "contain" the list.  It contains a reference to the interrupted function.

Comment: That's not a good test. `range` objects don't hold anything except like 3 numbers, so increasing the "size" of the range doesn't affect the size of the object.

`a` grows because putting the range in a list forces each number to be realized because lists actually hold elements.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` is simply not that useful of a function, since it only tells you the size of the object itself - not any other objects that are referred to by it.  So the size of `a` depends solely on the number of elements it contains - and not the complexity of those elements; the size of `b` is probably constant for all defined functions, and tells you nothing about the complexity of the function (that's all contained in sub-objects).  It *certainly* does not tell you anything about the runtime memory use of the function.

Answer (score 0):

`a` with a list comprehension is building and holding the entire object in memory.

`b` is a generator and it doesn't build nor hold the entire object in memory. Instead, it keeps state and runs up to yield every time you call `next()`.